# How can I expose an interactive neo4j visualization (safely) to users over the internet?

Tags: javascript, security, flask, neo4j

I'm trying to stand up a (non-commercial) [web application](https://github.com/rtruxal/webmap-webapp) that uses neo4j Community 3.5.2 as a backend.

The application interfaces with the graph in two ways:

- Server-side (safe) with flask to write new nodes and relationships
- Client-side (not safe) to read using [neovis.js](https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neovis.js) which, as far as I can tell with my limited JS knowledge, requires me to embed credentials in client-side code.

It makes me seriously queezy to allow clients to access an internet-exposed DB directly but, and again as far as I can tell, it's the only way I can keep a visualization interactive for my site's users. Is that correct?

Assuming it is, I'm exploring creating a user with read-only permissions to minimize exposure. The docs all seem to indicate I need the enterprise edition to do this. Is that correct?

Any general guidance or alternate approaches? This feels a bit wrong.

Comment: See [this site](https://igovsol.com/downloads.html) for what is apparently a free drop-in replacement for the Enterprise Edition.

Comment: I face the same issue.  If we want online users to modify a common graph, using credentials seems unavoidable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[iGov Inc](https://igovsol.com/) produces a [free version of the Enterprise Edition](https://igovsol.com/downloads.html) available from iGov Inc. It is built from the open source. Refer to the latter page for the latest downloads and FAQ.

Comment: Welll this technically wasn't the answer I was looking for, but the site now works (https://bscg.us) and this is good info that I'm going to use. I'ma give you the rep.